# How to use crypto and Buffer with vite in browser?

Tags: browser, buffer, cryptojs

I have a project need to encrypt data to send to backend.
and the crypto is like this:

```js
const NULL_IV = Buffer.from([]) // new Buffer([]);
const crypto = require('crypto'),
  algorithm = 'aes-256-ecb'

const { bodyCrypt:{password} } = require('../config/index')

function aesEncrypt(string = '') {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, NULL_IV)
  let encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(Buffer.from(string, 'utf8')), cipher.final()])
  return encrypted.toString('hex')
}


function aesDecrypt(string = '') {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, password, NULL_IV)
  let decrypted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(Buffer.from(string, 'hex')), decipher.final()])
  return decrypted.toString()
}


module.exports = {
  aesEncrypt,
  aesDecrypt,
}
```

How can I use this in browser?!!
I try to use cryptoJs to encrypt, but the ciphertext is changing and couldnt be decrypt by the code above.

```js
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')
const data = '1'
const key = '123456x3bxiinky1xzc95wcgc0p9p2p7'
const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  iv: '',
  keySize: 256
})
// 将加密后的数据转换成 Base64
const hexText= cipher.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

Comment: This is simply an AES-256 encryption in (insecure) ECB mode with PKCS7 padding. Every major JavaScript crypto library like WebCrypto or CryptoJS can do this. But maybe you are better off with TLS/SSL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Topaco,I will use https to make my broswer safer. how can I use CryptoJs to make the parameters the same as the code above?

Comment: See [_The Cipher Input_](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input). The key must be passed as `WordArray`: `const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('123456x3bxiinky1xzc95wcgc0p9p2p7')`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @Topaco.
If just want to encrypt request to a server or decrypt payload that a server send to us using "aes-256-ecb" algorithm.
Just use CryptoJS to make it works:

```js
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

import { crypt } from '@/config'

const { password } = crypt
const cryptKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(password)
const cryptoOptions = {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  iv: '',
  keySize: 256
}

/**
 * encrypt
 * @param {*} string
 * @returns {string}
 */
function aesEncrypt(string = '') {
  const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, cryptKey, cryptoOptions)
  return CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(cipher.ciphertext)
}

/**
 * decrypt
 * @param {*} string
 * @returns {string}
 */
function aesDecrypt(string = '') {
  const decipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    // make it params but not string that works.
    { ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(string) },
    cryptKey,
    cryptoOptions
  )
  return CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decipher)
}

export { aesEncrypt, aesDecrypt }
```

It doesnt need Buffer or crypto module that in nodejs environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how to work with native `node crypto` and `vite`, you can read this answer :

[TypeError: crypto.createCipheriv is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70478728/typeerror-crypto-createcipheriv-is-not-a-function/70479882#70479882)