# TypeError: crypto.createCipheriv is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollup, vite

vite+vue3 uses aes-cross to report: TypeError: crypto.createCipheriv is not a function
Version:
"vue": "^3.2.23",
"vite": "^2.6.4",
"aes-cross": "^1.0.9",

Answer (score 5):

To get `crypto` working in browser, follow instructions bellow

1. Add dependencies

`yarn add stream-browserify browserify-zlib events process util buffer`

2. Configure `vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      process: "process/browser",
      stream: "stream-browserify",
      zlib: "browserify-zlib",
      util: 'util'
    }
  }
})
```

3. Add JS to `index.html`

```html
<!-- [...] -->
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- node // crypto -->
<script>window.global = window;</script>
<script type="module">
    import { Buffer } from "buffer/"; // <-- no typo here ("/")
    import process from "process";
    import EventEmitter from "events";
        
    window.Buffer = Buffer;
    window.process = process;
    window.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
</script>
<!-- [...] -->
```

4. Add imports to `App.vue`, and testing function

in `App.vue`:

```
import crypto from 'crypto-browserify'
import { Buffer } from 'buffer/' // <-- no typo here ("/")

// test crypto 
function crypt() {
  // Node.js program to demonstrate the    
  // crypto.createCipheriv() method
  
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync("foobar", "salt", 1000, 32, 'sha512');
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
  var text = crypto.randomBytes(200)
  var ourCipherText = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), cipher.final()])
  console.log("ciphered text:", ourCipherText.toString('hex'))

  return ourCipherText.toString('hex');
}

[...]
```

Result ✅

[image: crypto browser screencast]

Comment: Holy mother of God!! I don't even understand how this is working, but it is.

Thanks for sharing this

Answer (score 0):

The function `crypto.createCipheriv` is a node.js only function meaning it is not available in the browser like in a Vue app. You should [look into](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) `SubtleCrypto` which provides native web features for many encryption purposes like AES. As always, it should be noted that one should be very careful and methodical when using low-level crypto primitives, especially regarding encryption. This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt) provides more examples of AES encryption specifically.