# crypto-browserify with vite

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, vite, cryptojs

In a vue3 application using vite, I am trying to use crypto-browserify. For a better understanding, I am trying to follow this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70478728/typeerror-crypto-createcipheriv-is-not-a-function) . However, when I'm testing in the development environment, the `createCipheriv` method works. Still, after building with Vite and running on a production server, it doesn't work. As far as I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong), Vite does not include any support for ES modules that import Node.js built-in modules, such as `crypto,` by default. Is there any workaround to use crypto `createCipheriv` along with vite?

I have tried looking around the window.crypto.subtle, but I am curious about using the nodejs builtins module (specifically crypto) with vite.